# Linux/C/mmap: Delay involved with IPC mechanism using Shared Memory Object in "dev/shm"

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-memory, mmap

I have two processes(let's say process1 and process2) which are independent processes running on different cores. Also, process1 has higher time frequency than process2.
I'm trying to send one piece of information from process1 and process2 using Shared memory.
I followed the following implementation.

1. Created a shared memory object of size 1 byte in /dev/shm(let's consider its name as "transfer_info"). Memory mapped this to the virtual address space of both the processes.
2. I'm writing the "transfer_info" with value '1' from process1.
3. process2 checks "transfer_info"(value is set as 1 by process1) and should immediately read it as '1'.
4. After some time, process1 writes '0' to "transfer_info".
5. process2 checks "transfer_info"(value is set as 0 by process1), it should be able to read '0' it immediately.

As the two processes are running independently in separate cores, after writing "transfer_info" from process1, process2 might also try to read the shared memory object parallelly sometimes. So process2 is missing the updated values sometimes.

As per my understanding, since shared memory object "transfer_info" uses the mmap() concept, again kernel has to do the flushing of data from the memory mapped region to the shared memory object "transfer_info".
So whenever process1 writes '1' to "transfer_info", it actually writes to the memory mapped region of process1. So kernel has to do the flushing from memory mapped region to shared memory object "transfer_info". If this flushing is delayed, then process2 can read '0' from "transfer_info".
So this mechanism is failing sometimes.
Is there any way to do flushing immediately that will help in this case? (I tried msync, but msync is not syncing because msync's behavior is undefined if used on a shared memory object as per the man page.)

Comment: Make sure you've declared the variable `volatile` to prevent optimizations that cache the memory in a register.

Comment: If you really are trying to deliver such a simple message (0/1) I suggest that you use a simpler IPC method, such as semaphores which are atomic. If you could write tell more about your code maybe we can come up with a more specific solution

Comment: @LITzman: I have explained what I'm trying to do in another post. Please find its link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75614561/linux-c-mmap-avoiding-the-flushing-of-memory-mapped-region-created-using-mmap                                                                                    As per this post, you can see that I'm not able to control the mmap() flushing. So, I'm trying to use explicit synchronization mechanism to prevent the reading of the memory mapped file in the process2. Based on the message from process1, process2 decides whether to read the memory mapped file or not.

Comment: @LITzman:  I'm using Shared memory object for IPC because, I read that it is the fastest way of IPC mechanism compared to all others.

Comment: There is nothing to "flush". The kernel only gets involved if there is a page fault. Try including `<stdatomic.h>` and make the "transfer_info" an `atomic_char`. Assuming `sharedp` is an `atomic_char *` pointing to the "transfer_info", use `atomic_store(sharedp, val);` to set "transfer_info"  and `val = atomic_load(sharedp);` to read "transfer_info".

Comment: In a **shared memory** model, both processes operates with the **same physical memory**. So, whenever one process writes to this memory, the other process may immediately read the value written. No "kernel flush" is involved at all. If your code behaves unexpectedly, then the problem is in your code. And without viewing the code, we cannot help you in fixing it.